# Get data from HTML and convert it to JSON

Tags: java, html, json

I have an output of HTML like this:

```
<input type='text' id='status' name='status' value='0'>
<input type='text' id='description' name='description' value='Success'>
<input type='text' id='COMPANY' name='COMPANY' value='201'>
```

and so on.

I would like to extract the id,name and value from this and convert them to JSON in java.

**Edit:** My JSPN output will look like

```
{"id": "status","name": "status", "value": "0"}
```

etc.

Comment: URL? I see a HTML snippet. Do you want to parse HTML? How should the resulting JSON look like? Please add an example.

Comment: For Java to Json convertion, use Gson framework

Comment: Do it in JavaScript and send the JSON to Java - see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/572939

Comment: json is not enought; you have a 2000 characters limitation; so , break the message into small parts; you dont know the company description length;

Comment: You can parse HTML with jsoup and generate Json with Jackson if you want to do this server side.

Comment: also, use JSON.stringify

Comment: thanks a lot. actually company description length is not so long.

still need help.

Answer (score 1):

just three steps

1.create a html Input element model which havs 3 properties: id,name,value.

2.extract values from the html file, you can use htmlparser and create a model instance using those values

3.convert model instance into json string.